# Repeat batch file with new ID

Tags: arrays, batch-file, automation

I have a batch file that looks like this, which takes a picture of a webpage and crops it:

```
cd C:\users\***\Downloads\IECapt-2008-06-10
IECapt --delay=10000 --url=http://test.com/picture.swf?id=1 --out="C:\users\***\My Documents\picture.png"
cd C:\users\***\My Documents
convert picture.png -trim picture.png

ftp -s:place_picture.txt
```

However, I have many URLs to work with. Each URL is the same, but the "id" part is different. For example:

```
http://test.com/picture.swf?id=1
http://test.com/picture.swf?id=324
```

My problem is that I have a bunch of URLs, and it would take a lot of time to replace the URL and run the script again for one image. So I was wondering, if there is a way that I can make this script more efficent and just add a list of the IDs and the script can automatically replace the id part and take images of all of the URL IDs I listed.

I would also need to give each picture that it outputs a separate name.

This is the "place_picture.txt" file:

```
open test.com
username
pass
hash
bin
lcd c:\users\***\My Documents
cd public_html/test.com/test
put picture.png
bye
```

Comment: You would also need to store the images in different files, right? And that would probably imply changes to `place_picture.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaetly I don't have access to a Windows computer,however this snippet should demonstrate how to impliment it...

```
@echo off
set map=5.87.123.76.098
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=." %%a in ("%map%") do (
    set token_a=%%a
    set token_b=%%b
    set token_c=%%c
    set token_d=%%d
    set token_e=%%e
)
set token
```

pause>nul

When I get on a Windows computer I'll experiment and help more.